# VMWare not in packages

Tags: package-management, vmware, vmware-workstation

What happens to VMWare package after installation?
VMWare works perfectly and I use it every day but I can not find it with any package manager. I need to back it up so that I do not have to reinstall if something goes wrong.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Followed this guide:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-vmware-workstation-player-on-ubuntu-18-04/
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
wget https://www.vmware.com/go/getplayer-linux
chmod +x getplayer-linux
sudo ./getplayer-linux

Comment: Those instructions seem to indicate that you didn't download a VMWare *package* at all. Looks like downloaded and used VMWare's custom software installer instead. So you won't be able to use any package tools or concepts on it.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to back it up so that I do not have to reinstall if something goes wrong.

In general, you either do a full system image, using tools such as Clonezilla or Acronis, or you set up a new system from scratch. Backing up individual, installed, programs is no easy feat in general, and it's simpler to use the installer to reinstall it.

Note that VMWare hands out a free trial, allowing you to download the product, as long as you register with an e-mail address.